# table size decrease and table ordering in column

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & T_{del}\ vs.\ T_{poi}                & T_{del} \ vs.\ Ben                 & T_{poi} \ vs.\ Ben  & Total  \\ 
\hline
ned                   &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
dui               &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
pil                   &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
kol                  &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &     &        \\
\cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

There are few things I want to change:

- I want to make it smaller by putting `T_{del}\ vs.\ T_{poi}` below each other. This way the width of the columns will decrease. I was unable to achieve this stacking because the whole layout is disrupted when I try to add an "enter."
- I have a 2 column layout and I was thinking of putting 2x2 the tables in a column. I don't know if that is possible? The table will be filled with small numbers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Should the four data columns have equal widths? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tabularray˛:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \def\del{\mathrm{del}}
    \def\poi{\mathrm{poi}}
    \def\Ben{\mathrm{Ben}}
    
\begin{tblr}{hline{1}={2-Z}{solid}, hline{2-Y}={1-Z}{solid}, 
             vline{1}={2-Y}{solid}, vline{2-X}={1-Y}{solid}, vline{Y-Z}={1-Z}{solid}, 
             colspec = {c *{4}{X[c,m]}},
              rowsep = 3pt}
        &   {$T_{\del}$\\ $\mathrm{vs.~T_{\poi}}$ }
            &   {$T_{\del}$\\ $\mathrm {vs.~Ben}$ }
                &   {$T_{\poi}$\\ $\mathrm{vs.~Ben}$ }
                    &   Total               \\
ned     &   &   &   &                       \\
dui     &   &   &   &                       \\
pil     &   &   &   &                       \\
kol     &   &   &   &                       \\
        &   &   &   &                       \\
    \cline{Z-Z}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can break lines with `\makecell` from the `makecell` package. the `l` option makes the `makecell` left aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \makecell[l]{$T_{del}$\ vs.\\ $T_{poi}$}                & \makecell[l]{$T_{del}$ \ vs.\\ Ben}                 & \makecell[l]{$T_{poi}$ \ vs.\\ Ben}  & Total  \\ 
\hline
ned                   &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
dui               &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
pil                   &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
kol                  &                      &                      &     &        \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &     &        \\
\cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the widths of columns 2 thru 5 to be the same, while allowing automatic line wrapping, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and set its overall width to `\colummwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} % for a more open 
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{| l | C | C | C | C |}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} 
& $T_{\mathrm{del}}$ vs.~$T_{\mathrm{poi}}$ 
& $T_{\mathrm{del}}$ vs.~Ben 
& $T_{\mathrm{poi}}$ vs.~Ben  
& Total  \\ 
\hline
ned          &      &      &      &      \\ 
\hline
dui          &      &      &      &      \\ 
\hline
pil          &      &      &      &      \\ 
\hline
kol          &      &      &      &      \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &     &  \\
\cline{5-5}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```